# Complexity of searching in a set of sets (C++)

Tags: c++, stl, time-complexity

I have a set of sets of positive integers `std::set<set::<int> > X`. Now I am given a set `std::set<int> V` and I want to know if it occurs in `X`. Obviously, this can be done by invoking the function find, so `X.find(V) != X.end()` should return true if `V` is in `X`.

My question is about the complexity of this operation, i.e. if `X` contains n sets of positive integers, what is time complexity of `X.find(V)`?

Comment: You'll find the answer [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find)

Comment: Combined with the information [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/operator_cmp)

Comment: @JohnFilleau according to the links provided, the complexity is O(m log(n)) where n is the size of X and m is largest possible size of V (assuming it is bounded).

Comment: @eto that's worst case, yeah. Best case is that no `set`s in `X` have the same size as `V`, in which case every comparison will be a constant time operation. So worst case `O(m log n)`, best case `O(log n)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching in a set is O(log n) in the number of elements, regardless of what the elements are composed of, even other sets. If the element *is* another set all you need is an ordering predicate (using the address of the object is a safe default). However, searching for an integer nested in the set of sets is going to be O(m log n) in general.

Comment: You have to take into account the complexity of the comparison operator for each set comparison when searching for a set within a set.

Comment: Is m here the size of the sets containing integers?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there are `e` sets in `X` such that the summation of sizes of all `e` sets is `n`, i.e., `|S1| + |S2| + ... + |Se| = n` then in the worst case `X.find(V)` will take `O(m*log(e))` where `m` is the size of `V`, i.e., `|V| = m`. As you can see it is independent of `n`.

Why? So a `set` in STL is typically implemented as a self-balancing binary search tree. Therefore the height of root is always `O(log(e))` where `e` is the total number of elements in the tree currently. Now notice that in our case the nodes of the tree are sets. `set` by default use less than `<` operator to compare with other `set` of the same type which takes `O(min(|S1|, |S2|))` time to compare.

Therefore in the worst case, if the set `V` we want to find is one of the leaves of `X` and all the nodes on the branch from the root to `V` have size `>= |V|` then every node comparison will take `O(|V|)` time and since there are `O(log(e))` nodes on this branch, it'll take us `O(m*log(e))` time.